# What is the correct antmatcher for this URI?

Tags: spring-security, spring-4

I have a controller with a mapping as such. I've provided values for the constants.

```
Constants.restApiUriPrefix = "rest/"
UserController.uriExtension = "users"

@RequestMapping(value = Constants.restApiUriPrefix + UserController.uriExtension)
public class UserController {


    @RequestMapping(params = "username")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseWithView<User> getUserByName(@RequestParam String username, @ModelAttribute User authenticatingUser) {
        return new ResponseWithView<User>(userService.findByUsername(username));
    }

}
```

When I run a test I use the following URI from the root context of the web server.

```
/rest/users?username=testUser%40gmail.com
```

Here are is my security config.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    if(environment == Environment.DEVELOPMENT) {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/" + Constants.restApiUriPrefix + TestHelperController.uriExtension + "/**").permitAll();
    }
    http.csrf().disable(); //TODO Someday fix this and turn csrf back on safely
    http
        .httpBasic()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/" + Constants.restApiUriPrefix + UserController.uriExtension + "?username=**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/" + Constants.restApiUriPrefix + UserController.uriExtension + "/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/" + Constants.restApiUriPrefix + UserController.uriExtension).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/" + Constants.restApiUriPrefix + "**").hasRole("USER");
}
```

I expect

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/" + Constants.restApiUriPrefix + UserController.uriExtension + "?username=**").permitAll()
```

to match my request to discover a user by username to come through without being challenged for authentication, but I am.

I'm using Spring 4.0.2.RELEASE and Spring Security 3.2.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working with the following ant matcher.

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/" + Constants.restApiUriPrefix + UserController.uriExtension + "*")
.permitAll()
```